# my notification code suddenly stopped working

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have an notification that works fine yesterday, the notification not appears and I don't remember I had touched the code..
that notification must be appears when I get the desired value and must open a pop up dialog we user touch it.

can anyone help please?

the notification code - in side service-:

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), PopUp.class);
notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

//how I tried to pass data    
notifyIntent.putExtra("text1", text1);       
notifyIntent.putExtra("text2", text2);

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, notifyIntent, 0);

// build notification
// the addAction re-use the same intent to keep the example short
Notification n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,CHANNEL_ID2)
.setContentTitle("check this")
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete)
.setContentIntent(pIntent)
.build();

NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

I'm using android studio emulator API 30
in the same service class I have a Notification and it is appearing to indicate that the service is working in the background, except the Notification that I but its code above it is not working suddenly

I don't know what is the problem, please help

Answer (score 1):

When Issuing the notification with notify the notificationId must be a unique int for each notification. Update your code to include a random unique notificationId

see below

```
//you can use the timestamp
 int notificationId = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));

 NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
  notificationManager.notify(notificationId, n);
```

[Android Create a Notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification)

Comment: I just use a createNotificationChannel2() as I have createNotificationChannel() for the service notification I it is working now! by using your method how will enhance or improve my code? sorry if my question considered silly